# My UART interrupt-based reading code crashes the ESP32

Tags: arduino, interrupt, esp32, uart

I am replacing my UART polling code by an interrupt based version but I get an `interrupt wdt on CPU1` as follows:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1). 

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x40098df4  PS      : 0x00060935  A0      : 0x80097d66  A1      : 0x3ffbf15c  
A2      : 0x3ffcd3b8  A3      : 0x3ffd0d6c  A4      : 0x00000004  A5      : 0x00060923  
A6      : 0x00060923  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x3ffd0d6c  A9      : 0x00000018  
A10     : 0x3ffd0d6c  A11     : 0x00000018  A12     : 0x3ffc8734  A13     : 0x00060923  
A14     : 0x007bf318  A15     : 0x003fffff  SAR     : 0x0000001e  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400860a1  LEND    : 0x400860a9  LCOUNT  : 0x00000027  
Core  1 was running in ISR context:
EPC1    : 0x40109c5b  EPC2    : 0x00000000  EPC3    : 0x00000000  EPC4    : 0x00000000


Backtrace:0x40098df1:0x3ffbf15c |<-CORRUPTED
```

Removing all logs makes no difference.

[UPDATE] I added the missing IRAM_ATTR to the interrupt handler, with no effect, still a wdt timeout.

It would be cool someone points me to the right direction.

My code is as follows and `processIncomingByteToForgeAMessage` is defined as static:

```cpp
#define BMS_UART_VERSION2 true

#define RXD GPIO_NUM_34
#define TXD GPIO_NUM_14

#define BmsSerial Serial2

const int MESSAGE_LENGTH = PACKET_LENGTH;
const byte START_BYTE = 0xA5;

/// The queue where we push incoming UART messages from the BMS
QueueHandle_t BmsUart :: incomingMessageQueue = xQueueCreate(100, PACKET_LENGTH);


/// @brief  Installs interrupt handler
void BmsUart :: setupInterrupt() {

    log("Installing UART interrupt handler");

    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(RXD), BmsUart :: processIncomingByteToForgeAMessage, FALLING); 
}

/// @brief Process incoming byte to forge a coherent message and push to the queue
void IRAM_ATTR BmsUart :: processIncomingByteToForgeAMessage() {
    static byte message[MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    static int messageIndex = 0;

    const int receivedInt = BmsSerial.read();

    // Nothing available?
    if (receivedInt<0) return;

    const byte receivedByte = receivedInt&0xff;

    // Waiting for start of message byte
    if (messageIndex == 0 && receivedByte != START_BYTE) {
        // Discard bytes until the start byte is found
        bmsUart.log("Start byte is wrong: %02x, discard till it is right (%02x)", receivedByte, START_BYTE);
        return;
    }

    bmsUart.log(">%02x ", receivedByte&0xff);

    // Add the received byte to the message buffer
    message[messageIndex++] = receivedByte;

    if (messageIndex>PACKET_LENGTH) {
        // Reset the index for the next message
        messageIndex = 0;
        bmsUart.error("Buffer overflow at %d bytes, resetting to 0", messageIndex);
    }

    if (messageIndex == MESSAGE_LENGTH) {

        const byte messageId = message[PACKET_MESSAGE_ID_OFFSET];


        const esp_err_t err = xQueueSend(BmsUart :: incomingMessageQueue, message, RS485_QUEUE_MAX_TICKS_DELAY);
        
        switch (err){
        // Ok, posted in the queue?
        case pdTRUE: break;
        // Queue is full?
        case errQUEUE_FULL:
            bmsUart.warn("Queue is full: unable to post the message %02x to the queue", messageId);
            break;  
        default:
            bmsUart.warn("Error %02x: Unable to post the message %02x to the queue, even after %d ticks", err, messageId, RS485_QUEUE_MAX_TICKS_DELAY);
            break;
        }

        // Reset the index for the next message
        messageIndex = 0;
    }
}



/// @brief Gets pending message if any
/// @param message A PACKET_LENGTH -sized byte buffer to hold the next message, if nay
/// @return true if a message is there otherwise false

bool BmsUart :: getNextMessage(byte *message) {
    // If a message is available, process it
    
    if (xQueueReceive(incomingMessageQueue, &message, RS485_QUEUE_MAX_TICKS_DELAY) == pdPASS) {
    
        // Log the available message
        logMessage("Pending message", message);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}





void BmsUart :: setup() {
    /// Stack depth
    stackDepth = 4000;

    /// Every 300 mseconds
    taskExecutionPeriod = 300;


    log("Serial connection thru UART2 (pins %d/%d)…", RXD,TXD);



    #if BMS_UART_VERSION2
    // ==  Installs interrupt handler
    setupInterrupt();
    #endif

    // == driver output enable
    //pinMode (ENABLE_PIN, OUTPUT); 
    BmsSerial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXD, TXD);



    while (!BmsSerial) {
        log(">.");
    }

    log("BmsSerial began!");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing way too much work inside the interrupt handler, potentially preventing other interrupt service routines from running and therefore triggering the Interrupt WDT. Interrupt handlers should perform the minimum possible amount of computation.

One important issue are the logging messages inside the interrupt handler, just removing them might solve your problem, but you should consider deferring all the processing you are currently doing in the handler to a separate task (for example, using the interrupt handler just to send data to a queue).

Besides that, you are configuring the interrupt just using the falling edge of the UART Rx pin, which is not the right way of doing it. There should be UART specific interrupts associated to each serial port, and you should be using those ones. Otherwise, the interrupt would be triggered multiple times during a UART transmission, aggravating the Interrupt WDT issue.

If you still need more time and are absolutely sure about the consequences of what you are doing, you can also consider increasing the timeout value of the Interrupt WDT (via [`menuconfig`](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/kconfig.html#config-esp-int-wdt-timeout-ms)).

Comment: As I told in the question, removing all logs changes nothing to the game

Comment: I missed that part, but the rest of the answer still applies. I just edited my answer with something else I noticed related to the interrupt you are configuring.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`xQueueSendFromISR`](https://www.freertos.org/a00119.html) from within an interrupt handler to post your message.

Are you sure that a call to `BmsSerial.read()` doesn't block waiting for incoming data? Interrupt handlers wait for nobody - mostly because rest of the system is frozen, waiting for the interrupt handler to finish.